# How to fade in a hidden JavaFX label

Tags: java, javafx

How can I add fancy JavaFX events on hidden items?

For example, I'd like to use the "Fade" effect when I show a hidden Label, triggered by button click.

How can I add the effect when the method below is called?

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    label.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [FadeTransition](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html):

```
@FXML private Label label;

private FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(
    Duration.millis(3000)
);

public void initialize() {
    fadeIn.setNode(label);

    fadeIn.setFromValue(0.0);
    fadeIn.setToValue(1.0);
    fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);
    fadeIn.setAutoReverse(false);
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (!label.isVisible()) {
        label.setVisible(true);
        fadeIn.playFromStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note: fadeIn should be defined out of method scope. Otherwise there will be many non terminated (unstopped) FadeTransition instances on each button action, resulting memory leakage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer  [Uluk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/682495/uluk-biy). Sorry for the late reply to your answer, but my connection's been out completely till now. Thank you again. It works!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Uluk, I was assuming that the framework would cleanup the FadeTransition after it finished playing, but perhaps it does not, best to code defensively and assume that it doesn't.  Updated answer to show a pattern which should not leak.